# What do you call a stack of ordering forms?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Sometimes, a restaurant will prepare **order forms** for customers to
>   tick which food/drinks that they want to order. Then the
>   waiter/waitress will come to collect them and reconfirm with the
>   customers their order.

Is there a single word for order forms?

Comment: Anything wrong with the three-syllable *order form*?

Comment: If I ran the restaurant, I'd probably call it a 'menu'.

Comment: @WS2 absolutely not... but why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kitchen staff will refer to these as *tickets,* although the waiter may choose to stick with *order form* when communicating with the customer, as the term ticket is usually not referenced for front-of-house activities.